# How do you access a Ruby instance variable/method dynamically?

Tags: php, ruby, variables, dynamic

How do you access a Ruby instance variable/method dynamically? I'm basically after the Ruby equivalent of the following PHP code...

```
$foo = new Foo;
$bar = 'bar';

echo $foo->$bar;
echo $foo->$bar();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) method takes a method name. You can call [`#intern`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/intern) on a string to make a Symbol from it. So this is the equivalent:

```
foo = Foo.new
bar = 'bar'
puts foo.send(bar.intern)
```

Instance variables are private by default. To expose them, the normal thing to do is to add a `attr_reader` call to the class definition:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar

  def initialize(value_of_bar)
    @bar = value_of_bar
  end
end

bar = 'bar'
foo = Foo.new("bar_value")
puts foo.bar # => "bar_value"
puts foo.send(:bar) # => "bar_value"
puts foo.send(bar.intern) # => "bar_value"
```

To reach in and access instance variables that don't have reader methods, `#instance_variable_get` will work, though it's often better to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @x = 10
  end
  def test
    @x
  end
end
foo = Foo.new
foo.instance_variables
# => [:@x]
foo.instance_variable_get(:@x)
# => 10
Foo.instance_methods(false)
# => [:test]
Foo.instance_methods(false).map{|i| foo.method(i).call}
# => [10]
Foo.instance_methods(false).map{|i| foo.send(i)}
# => [10]
```

Answer (score 1):

`instance_variable_get` (Don't forget the `@`).

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @ivar = "hello"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new

foo.instance_variable_get :@ivar
#=> "hello"
```

Alternatively provide an accessor on the class

```
class Bar
  attr_reader :ivar

  def intialize
    @ivar = "hey"
  end
end

Bar.new.ivar
#=> "hey"
```